# Ubuntu Minimal of less than 100 MB

Tags: 14.04

I want a minimal Ubuntu of less than 100 MB after installation!! Ubuntu with only terminal no GUI!!!
Actually i want to install a terminal based Ubuntu with no GUI as my virtual machine
Can anybody help???

Comment: cross posting http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/237558/ubuntu-minimal-of-less-than-100-mb

Comment: You might want to take a look at [DSL](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org)

Answer (score 1):

You can download the ubuntu mini.iso. The mini.iso is a netinstall image and is great for doing what you want to do. When you get to the part of the installation that lists the different desktops, just basically unselect everything or almost everything.

You may want some minimal stuff like a server of maybe not, the choice is up to you.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

Comment: i am installing it by VMware player as my virtual machine. it doesn't gives options to unselect desktops. it downloads packages at installation time . am i right?? or i can unselect everything as you told??

Comment: vmware? sorry i don't know

Comment: Having installed the Ubuntu min.iso myself with only the terminal, no GUI at all, I can report that it installs nothing extra if you select the minimal CLI installation, not even the X server, so all you get is the terminal. Installing it in VMware or VirtualBox does the same. This is not a 100MB installation of Ubuntu  however, it's not even close to being that small, but it's very nice because of that.

Comment: i am using VMware Player for Linux 64-bit Linux on my 64 bit ubuntu. i have downloaded it from https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_player/7_0 it doesn't gives any option for unselectig anything it downloads packages from mirrior site given to it. sorry if it is a dumb question but i will happy if you help me.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't have an Ubuntu system that uses less than 100mb. A minimal installation of Ubuntu 14.04 uses roughly 360Mb of space - 125mb just for the kernel and it's modules and the rest for the base system.

Answer (score 1):

All major distros can't be installed on 100 MB, they're not meant for that.
You might search for some specialized distro that fits your needs on [DistroWatch](http://distrowatch.com/).